# SOAP client in Node.js - XML signature validation failed

Tags: c#, node.js, xml, soap, x509

I am using [this node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) which comes with WS-Security X509 certificate support. Then, I'm calling a local SOAP service written in C# which uses the [SignedXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml?view=net-5.0) class to check the signature from incoming requests. However, I didn't get any success passing through signature validation.

I've captured the whole SOAP envelope and tried to verify the signed xml online [here](https://tools.chilkat.io/xmlDsigVerify.cshtml). I'm getting this result:

```
Signature Verified 
Number of Reference Digests = 2 
Reference 1 digestis valid. 
Reference 2 digest is invalid because the computed digest differs from the digest in the XML.
```

The second reference is the Timestamp.

[The envelope](https://justpaste.it/6ycv5)

As you can see I'm using the http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n# canonicalization method. The issues might be in some namespaces or whitespaces.

If anyone has experienced this before, please share your ideas and possible solutions. Thank you!

Comment: The evelope shows you are getting HTTP Error 403 forbidden.  Your request is bad, not the response.  The SOAP is the response.  Most likely you are using a URL with HTTP and Server wants HTTPS (secure with TLS).  So either your URL is wrong or the TLS authentication is failing.  403 could be caused by other issues but I'm guessing from working with lots of posting it is more likely the TLS is failing.

Comment: @jdweng Pastebin for some reason made it private. Here is the envelope: https://justpaste.it/6ycv5

Comment: Is signatue still failing?  You are using very old encryption algorithms.  The server may not allow the old algorithms which may be considered a security risk.  Not sure.  Did you try using any online checkers to see if signature is valid?

Comment: I literally posted the online tool I used to verify the signature and it has some problems with the timestamp. Algorithms are not a issue.